# ColdFusion searching robots.txt for specific page exception

Tags: coldfusion

We're adding some functionality to our CMS whereby when a user creates a page, they can select an option to allow/disallow search engine indexing of that page.

If they select yes, then something like the following would apply:

```
<cfif request.variables.indexable eq 0>
<cffile 
    action = "append"
    file = "C:\websites\robots.txt"
    output = "Disallow: /blocked-page.cfm"
    addNewLine = "yes">
<cfelse>
<!-- check if page already disallowed in robots.txt and remove line if it does --->
</cfif>
```

It's the `<cfelse>` clause I need help with.
What would be the best way to parse robots.txt to see if this page had already been disallowed? Would it be a cffile action="read", then do a find() on the read variable?

Actually, the check on whether the page has already been disallowed would probably go further up, to avoid double-adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep the list of pages in database and each page record has a `indexable` bit, right? If yes, simpler and more reliable approach would be to generate new robots.txt each time some page is added/deleted/changes indexable bit.

```
<!--- TODO: query for indexable pages ---->

<!--- lock the code to prevent concurrent changes --->

<cflock name="robots.txt" type="exclusive" timeout="30">

    <!--- flush the file, or simply start with writing something --->

    <cffile 
        action = "write"
        file = "C:\websites\robots.txt"
        output = "Sitemap: http://www.mywebsite.tld/sitemap.xml"
        addNewLine = "yes">

    <!--- append indexable entry to the file --->

    <cfloop query="getPages">

        <!--- we assume that page names are not entered by user (= safe names) --->

        <cffile 
            action = "append"
            file = "C:\websites\robots.txt"
            output = "Disallow: /#getPages.name#.cfm"
            addNewLine = "yes">

    </cfloop>

</cflock>
```

Sample code is not tested, be aware of typos/bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Robots.txt files for this purpose is a bad idea.  [Robots.txt is not a security measure](http://diovo.com/2008/09/robotstxt-is-not-a-security-measure/) and you're handing "evildoers" a list of pages that you don't want indexed.

You're much better off using the [robots meta tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag), which will not provide anyone with a list of pages that you don't want indexed, and gives you greater control of the individual actions a robot can perform.

Using the meta tags, you would simply output the tags when generating the page as usual.

Comment: Please tell, why do you think this is about security? I can't see anything like that in the question.

Comment: @Sergii It's a CMS, how to do you know the admin wont use the feature for security? Even if security isn't a concern, you're still providing a list of all pages that you don't want listed. Some might consider that to be self defeating. The robots meta tag solves that issue, gives greater control of the robot's behaviour, and it's easier to implement.  Additionally, using Robots.txt instead of the meta tags doesn't mean the pages won't show in Google, which one would presume is the intent of the question. http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/googlebot-keep-out/ under "Obscure note #1"

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--- dummy page to block --->
<cfset request.pageToBlock = "/blocked-page.cfm" />

<!--- read in current robots.txt --->
<cffile action="read" file="#expandPath('robots.txt')#" variable="data" />
<!--- build a struct of all blocked pages --->
<cfset pages = {} />
<cfloop list="#data#" delimiters="#chr(10)#" index="i">
    <cfset pages[listLast(i,' ')] = '' />
</cfloop>


<cfif request.variables.indexable eq 0>
    <!--- If the page is not yet blocked add it --->
    <cfif not structKeyExists(pages,pageToBlock)>
        <cffile action="append" file="C:\websites\robots.txt" 
             output="Disallow: #request.pageToBLock#" addNewLine="yes" />
        <!--- not sure if this is in a loop but if it is add it to the struct for nex iteration --->
        <cfset pages[request.pageToBlock] = '' />
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

This should do it.  Read in the file, loop over it and build a struct of the bloocked pages.  Only add a new page if it's not already blocked.